# JavaScript/jQuery Userscript to thwart redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, onbeforeunload

Okay, using a Userscript, how can I detect and stop a page redirection? I don't own the pages source.

Here's what happens normally on the page:

1. User clicks a link
2. Page checks with the server via AJAX by sending some data regarding the link clicked to a PHP page
3. The PHP page clearly replies with something, because then the user is redirected to another page.

So, still allowing the AJAX request to go through in step 2, how can I thwart the redirection of the user by using a userscript?

From what I understand, window.onbeforeunload really only helps by giving a dialog before the user moves pages - I don't want this, I want to silently thwart the redirection.

EDIT: I think window.stop() will work to stop the page from changing, but detecting that it will change might be a challenge...

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.something.com';
window.stop();
```

Seems to work. But detecting that location.href is changing?

Comment: Do you want to prevent the redirection when clicking a link?

Comment: Not exactly. When you click the link, it sends an AJAX query which is crucial. It's only when the AJAX query succeeds that there's a redirect.

Comment: Could you post more of the code? Say, how the link is setup?

Answer (score -3):

An ordinary link is by-default a request to load another page, and that request is independent of anything else you might do as a result of clicking on the link.  However, you don't have to use the ordinary kind of link; look at this:

```
<a style="color:#0000ff;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;"
onclick="window.name='here';window.open('http://www.example.com/newpage.htm',
'here');">New Page</a>
```

That HTML code will look exactly like an ordinary link, and work exactly like an ordinary link, to load a new page into the current page.  But it is actually a JavaScript* construct, and that means you can intercept it to do other things, for example:

```
<a style="color:#0000ff;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;"
onclick="window.name='here';intercept();">New Page</a>
```

You can now write a JavaScript function named "intercept()" to decide whether or not to load the new page (do your AJAX call).  If you do decide to load the new page, then you only need to do this inside the AJAX call-back function:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/newpage.htm','here');
```

If you have multiple links on the page, just specify a parameter in the `intercept()` function-call (that is, `intercept('newpage.htm');` or `intercept('altpage.htm');` or `intercept('diffpage.htm');` ) and then inside the intercept function simply put the the received string into a global variable, so that the `window.open()` function-call, inside the AJAX call-back function, can use the global variable to open the correct new page.

*The user, of course has to have JavaScript enabled in the browser for the link to work.  But then JavaScript needs to be enabled for AJAX to work, too, so, not-a-problem.

Comment: I don't own the website and have no control over their source. This doesn't seem like its answering my question.

Comment: Then you need to fix your question, because you did NOT say that you had no control over the page-content, and my Answer is perfectly good for anyone who has a problem like you've described, and has control over the page-content.

Comment: I assumed it was intuitive given that I wish to do this in a userscript, not a page content script.

Comment: For someone who knows what a userscript is, you may be right.  As it happens, I've been using the 3rd edition of David Flanagan's "JavaScript Definitive Guide" for a number of years now, and it doesn't mention userscripts.  There are times when you need to stop trying to stay up-to-date with language changes, and get your hands dirty writing actual code (else the writing might never get done!).  So it goes....

Comment: Sorry, but I was looking for an Userscript solution... your answer is totally unrelated.